# Is there a way to edit google spreadsheets offline on iphone?

Tags: iphone, google-apps, google-docs

I downloaded their app but it doesn't let me edit them when offline. But some websites seem to say it's possible to edit them offline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, but I'd assume Google is working on that to eventually allow you to.

> Offline editing isn’t currently supported.

[<sup><sub>(Source)</sub></sup>](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=107975)